# Who is implementing the ISO8601 in correct way? Swift or Spring?

Tags: swift, spring, iso

The default behaviour of Jackson serializer used in Spring framework is as the following: (from the spring-data-rest source code):

```
        /**
         * The most common ISO DateTime Format {@code yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ},
         * e.g. "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00".
         * <p>This is the default if no annotation value is specified.
         */
```

So one example of such formatting could be `2019-03-20T11:18:46.000+0000`. Swift has also ISO8601 decoder but in fact, for Swift this string has just invalid format because of miliseconds. If you remove the milliseconds part, swift can successfully deserialize the string.

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let createdAt: Date
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

let data2 = "{\"createdAt\": \"2018-12-05T14:05:35.000+0000\"}".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoded2 = try! decoder.decode(Test.self, from: data2)
```

Swift is referring to RFC 3339 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt and there is no mention of milliseconds. My question is - What format is correct then? If something is in ISO format which should be stricly defined, I dont normally expect to write a custom deserializer (swift) or defining the custom pattern for serializing (spring).

Answer (score 3):

You should set iso8601 options. You can do it by using ISO8601DateFormatter.

```
struct Test: Codable {
    let createdAt: Date
}

enum CustomDateDecodingStrategy {

    private static let formatter: ISO8601DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.formatOptions = [
            .withFullDate,
            .withFullTime,
            .withTimeZone,
            .withFractionalSeconds
        ]
        return formatter
    }()

    static func decode(_ decoder: Decoder) throws -> Date {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            return date
        } else {
            throw NSError(domain: "date", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }

}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(CustomDateDecodingStrategy.decode)

let data2 = "{\"createdAt\": \"2018-12-05T14:05:35.000+0000\"}".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoded2 = try! decoder.decode(Test.self, from: data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Page 23 of [the ISO8601 2016 draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20171019211402/https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-1.pdf):

> If necessary for a particular application a decimal fraction of hour, minute or second may be included. If a decimal fraction is included, lower order time elements(if any) shall be omitted and the decimal fraction  shall  be  divided  from  the  integer  part  by  the  decimal  sign  specified  in  ISO  31-0,  i.e.  the comma [,] or full stop [.]. Of these, the comma is the preferred sign. If the magnitude of the number is less than unity, the decimal sign shall be preceded by two zeros in accordance with 3.6.

So `2018-12-05T14:05:35.000` is legal. While RFC 3339 doesn't mention milliseconds by name, it does talk about "fractions", e.g.:

> The format defined below includes only one rarely used option:
>      fractions of a second.  It is expected that this will be used only by
>      applications which require strict ordering of date/time stamps or
>      which have an unusual precision requirement.

and

> ISO 8601 also requires (in section 5.3.1.3) that a decimal fraction
>      be proceeded by a "0" if less than unity.  Annex B.2 of ISO 8601
>      gives examples where the decimal fractions are not preceded by a "0".
>      This grammar assumes section 5.3.1.3 is correct and that Annex B.2 is
>      in error.